# A probabilistic approach towards counting

Tags: probability, combinatorics, markov-chains, random-walk

Consider the following game. We start with the empty string and then repeatedly choose one of the following three actions uniformly at random with the same probability of occurrence(1/3 each) :

1. Append an $\mathtt{A}$ to the end of the string.
2. Append a $\mathtt{B}$ to the end of the string.
3. Remove the last symbol from the string (or do nothing if the string is empty).

**Main question.** How many steps on average does it take until the string is exactly $\mathtt{ABBB}$?

**Bonus question.** How many steps on average does it take until the string contains $\mathtt{ABBB}$ as a substring? for instance: $\mathtt{BBAABBBA}$

P.S.I gave this problem a try and what I realized could be summed in this way: 1-the number of actions has got to be an even number greater or equal to 4. 2- Then try and add two actions(by adding and removing an undesired letter. 3-Count how many desired strings can be constructed after following steps 1 and two. 4-Then calculate the weighted average of the numbers above. but the problem is it is an infinite series and I'm not sure whether it's a convergent series or not. by the way, this is my initial thoughts which might be severely distorted!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in your P.S. Btw, have you tried out anything to find this? You should add that to your question.

Comment: Do you mean that what is typed consists solely of "ABBB" and "BABBB" doesn't count?

Comment: Both variants of the question seem to be quite challenging. It feels like it ought to be possible to attack them elementarily by solving several largish systems of linear equations, after massaging the problem a bit to trade the infinite state space for a recurrence. But it gets very complex, and feels like there ought to be a general theory to help keep track of things. Google finds that there's a concept of _recursive Markov chains_ which might be helpful, but I haven't delved into the details of that.

Comment: I've attempted a rewrite to make your question more mathematically precise. Please shout out if my reformulation doesn't match the problem you intended to pose.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, @HenningMakholm  for posting a much more comprehensive version of the problem.

Comment: You're welcome. If my interpretation of the first question as a conditional expectation is not right, please clarify further.

Comment: If I were to guess, the "Main question" would have an infinite expectation unless you weighted "action 3" to occur with probability $\geq 1/2$.

The bonus question is more interesting, but I don't have any intuition on it.

Comment: Indeed, for the main question, if the probability of 'deletion' is $\leq1/2$, then the expected number of operations is infinite. Moreover, if the probability of deletion is $<\frac{1}{2}$ then the word $\mathtt{ABBB}$ is never achieved with positive probability. The bonus question seems much more interesting, and due to the lack of Markov property, it will be considerably hard to analyze compared to the model without deletion.